# Use mac filtering for router that filters all directly connected only

Tags: router

I have a network where the internet is provided by a main router of the building. Each flat in the building has a router. The devices in the flat including mobiles etc should connect to the flat router.

I wanna make sure every flat connects through its router so I tried to setup a mac filter and added the flat router mac address in the whitelist of mc filtering.

The problem i faced with this setup is that the devices that will connect to flat router wont get internet access until the are added to the white list.

Is there a way to allow those devices without adding them to whitelist

Comment: I'm afraid home/residential networking is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help]. Generally, you need to make up your mind if you permit routers/devices by port (without ado), by MAC address, 802.1X, PPPoE, MACsec authentication, ... which all have their pros and cons.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is *port security*. Attempting to maintain a static whitelist will be a nightmare, and won't actually force anyone to use "your" router -- they just need to clone the MAC of that router.

If your switch supports port-security, just set it to allow only one learned MAC. (this is basically how all US cable operators limit subscribers to one device. the modem learns the MAC of the first device it sees, and basically ignores the rest.)